# Unacceptable performance rendering PDF Tables with ITextSharp and PDFSharp

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdfsharp

I am trying to generate PDF files containing large numbers of tables.  Each PDF could potentially be 150 pages in length.

When using [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), the file sizes are up to 16 megabytes and have no noticeable shrinkage when zipped.

When using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharp/), the file size is very reasonable at 2 or 3 megabytes but it takes an unacceptable length of time (I canceled it after 3 minutes) to generate the document.

Does anybody have a suggestion of generating complex PDF files efficiently w/ .NET?

Answer (score 3):

You say PDFsharp but you actually use MigraDoc.
Yes, table rendering with MigraDoc Foundation is still slow with version 1.32.

Version 1.50 brought huge speed improvements in general and with 1.50 beta 2 we particular tackled slow table rendering.

Test results:
PDFsharp + MigraDoc WPF 1.32.2608:
Average: 24.443 seconds
MigraDoc-1.32-patched-release (WPF) from Pakeha:
Average: 9.114 seconds
PDFsharp + MigraDoc (WPF) 1.50.3638-beta:
Average: 16.114 seconds
PDFsharp + MigraDoc (WPF) 1.50.3915-beta2:
Average: 1.559 seconds

See also:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9379#p9379

Comment: was this ever fixed or is performance still an issue here?

Comment: Performance was improved with version 1.50, especially version 1.50 beta 2 was a big step forward.

Answer (score 3):

There has been a patch submitted which improves table rendering performance massively - the bigger the table the bigger the improvement apparently.  On running a quick test my results for a table with 200 rows were:

- (Original DLL) [ResultsGenerator] [Info] PDF results written in: 00:00:25.9754857
- (Patched DLL)  [ResultsGenerator] [Info] PDF results written in: 00:00:03.9472258

http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=679&start=0#p4888

Comment: Performance was improved with version 1.50, especially version 1.50 beta 2 was a big step forward.  Version 1.50 RC2 without patch should be much faster than version 1.32 with this patch.

Answer (score 0):

When my company tested out the performance of writing out PDFs we chose [TallPDF](http://www.tallcomponents.com/tallpdf3.aspx) by TallComponents.  I wrote a wrapper around the lib and thought it was pretty easy to work with and did perform well on large datasets.